# WHERE clause filters ORDER

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

```
select *
from Transaction
INNER JOIN Merchant on Transaction.MerchantId = Merchant.Id
where Transaction.Id > 0
  AND Merchant.Id in (213123, 321441, 213332)
```

[image]
Does the above execution plan is showing that Merchant.Id filter is executing before Transaction.Id filter. Shouldn't Transaction.Id filter be executed first? As I have written it before?

Comment: The optimizer decides the execution order.

Comment: @jarlh So you mean that it doesn't matter what order programmer has written filter in?

Comment: Correct. The join order and where clause order make no difference. The optimizer may chose a completely different order!

Comment: Yes, in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

Comment: I should jolly well hope `Merchant.Id in (213123, 321441, 213332)` was executed first (unlike your sql) why would you want all transaction.id evaluated if the range of id's only relates to some joined rows? merchantid is of more importance in that query than transactonid due to the join (and why evaluate transaction.id > 0 anyway? its probably a unique identity which the optimizer knows about too).

Comment: @Used_By_Already its an example that is why transaction.id > 0 :P

Comment: I realize that, but the optimizer also makes assessments on what is important. If you used a different predicate you could a different result ,  but you should not assume that your written logic is necessarily the best path.